# Вывести название товара в шаблоне комментария woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Суть вопроса заключается в следующем. Делаю вывод комментариев по товарам. Все супер но не могу никак найти информацию как мне получить айдишник товара к которому принадлежит тот или иной комментарий. Вот функкция которая обрабатывает стиль комментария

```html
function mytheme_comment_index( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
 
 if ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) {
  $tag       = 'div';
  $add_below = 'comment';
 } else {
  $tag       = 'div';
  $add_below = 'div-comment';
 }

 
 ?>

 <div class="testimonials-index-wraper-block"  id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
 <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) { ?>
  <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body"><?php
 } ?>
<div class="title title-product-rev-index">


 <h6>
  <?php echo get_the_title( '2410' ); ?>
  <?php echo get_the_title( '2410' ); ?>
 </h6>
</div>
 <div class="comment-author avatar">
  <?php
  if ( $args['avatar_size'] != 0 ) {
   echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] );
  }
  
  ?>
 </div>
 
 <div class="author">
     <div class="name">
     <?php if (pll_current_language() == 'ru')
     { echo('Имя'); }
     if (pll_current_language() == 'ua')
     { echo("Ім`я"); }
     if (pll_current_language() == 'en')
     { echo('Name'); }
     ?>
     </div>
     <div class="city">
     <?php
     printf(
   __( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>' ),
   get_comment_author_link()
  );
     ?>
     </div>
    </div>

 <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) { ?>
  <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation">
   <?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?>
  </em><br/>
 <?php } ?>

 

 <?php comment_text(); ?>

 

 <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) { ?>
  </div>
 <?php }
 
}
```

Так вот может кто вкурсе каким образом возможно в h6 вместо 2410 автоматом чтобы подставлялся нужный ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Продукт - это кастомный пост тип. Коментраии имеют свойство comment_post_ID в котором хранится ID поста к которому он пренадлежит.

```
echo get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID );
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, шикарно все.